# How to pre-select dynamically created radio button based on json input via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

In the below script, I am dynamically creating radio-buttons (green/yellow/red) as status next to some categories.

Categories and status (1-green, 2-yellow, 3-red) will both be received via json objects. My aim is to display current status as pre-selected radio button. 
eg: In the below form say `{"category":"System Availability","status":"1"}` indicates that System Availability status is 1 that means Green, how can I select Green button pre-selected? If it comes as 0, nothing should be selected.

Here is the running-code that doesn't have any functionality of pre-selecting radio button based on json input. At the end, my aim is to update the database back via json.

Thanks for your time, in attempting to help!

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var appStatus = [{
             "category": "Overall Status",
             "status": "0"
         }, {
             "category": "System Availability",
             "status": "1"
         }, {
             "category": "Whatever",
             "status": "2"
         }];
         var tr;
         for (var i = 0; i < appStatus.length; i++) {
             tr = $('<tr/>');
             tr.append("<td>" + appStatus[i].category + "</td>");
             tr.append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="1" id="inlineRadio1"><font color="green">Green &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"><font color="yellow">Yellow &emsp;</font></label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio3" value="3"> <font color="red">Red</font></label><td></tr>');
             $('table').append(tr);
         }


         $('#result').on('click', function() {
             var new_status = [];
             $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
                 new_status.push({
                     category: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                     status: $(this).find(':radio:checked').val()
                 });
             });

             console.log(new_status);
         });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover"><thead>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Status</th>
</thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be oversimplifying this, but if you want to preselect a radio button, just alter the HTML you're appending so that the `<input>` is rendered with a `checked` attribute when it should be selected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var appStatus = [{
  "category": "Overall Status",
  "status": "0"
 }, {
  "category": "System Availability",
  "status": "1"
 }, {
  "category": "Whatever",
  "status": "2"
 }];
 var tr;
 for (var i = 0; i < appStatus.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td>" + appStatus[i].category + "</td>");
  tr.append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="1" id="inlineRadio1"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '1' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
   '><font color="green">Green &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '2' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
   '><font color="yellow">Yellow &emsp;</font></label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio3" value="3"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '3' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + '> <font color="red">Red</font></label><td></tr>');
  $('table').append(tr);
 }


 $('#result').on('click', function() {
  var new_status = [];
  $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
   new_status.push({
    category: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
    status: $(this).find(':radio:checked').val()
   });
  });

  console.log(new_status);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover"><thead>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Status</th>
</thead>
</table>
```